# MVC pass data from one ViewController to another ViewController failed(all steps was done)

Tags: ios, objective-c

Today I use MVC to build a photo album.But I can't get data in ViewControllerB that pass from ViewControllerA,I read this article  here is link ([Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers/9736559#9736559)), and check all the steps I do.

Here is code in `ViewControllerA`:

```
PhotoViewController *photoVC = [[PhotoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
photoVC.images = images;
photoVC.index  = index;
photoVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
[self presentViewController:photoVC animated:YES completion:^{
    // code
}];
```

Here is code in `ViewControllerB`:

```
@interface PhotoViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic ,retain) NSMutableArray *images;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger        index;

@end
```

here is .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.images);
}
```

But I got nothing, I don't know where I was wrong, how to make it right?? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please check this [link][1]  its clearly explained here. This is may help you to do better and understand better.



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Comment: Yeah, I read this article for times some days ago, and I read it today for answers, I did step by step, but it doesn't work.

Comment: have you tried using protocols?

Comment: Have you checked that `images` is actually non-nil before the call? Are you sure your view controller is instantiated through this code (and not via a storyboard segue for instance)?

Comment: Thanks, I found the reason , I wrote some sentence in VCB's init method, when I moved them to viewDidLod method, data can be get. I don't try protocols, I use protocols send data from VCB to VCA. and that 'images' is not non-nil , storyboard segue I will learn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can instantiate your `PhotoViewController` from:

```
PhotoViewController *photoVC = [[PhotoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

Do this instead:

```
PhotoViewController *photoVC = [[PhotoViewController alloc] init];
```

Or you should pass the identifier to `nibName`, otherwise how can it find out which Nib file to load?

**EDIT:**
You should put this code section inside the animation completion block. `UIViewController` is not full instantiated when you pass data like you did.

```
[self presentViewController:photoVC animated:YES completion:^{
    photoVC.images = images;
    photoVC.index  = index;
    photoVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
}];
```

**EDIT 2:**
Reason:

> The nib file you specify is not loaded right away. It is loaded the
>   first time the view controller's view is accessed. If you want to
>   perform additional initialization after the nib file is loaded,
>   override the viewDidLoad method and perform your tasks there.

Comment: I did init photoVC like  `PhotoViewController *photoVC = [[PhotoViewController alloc] init];` but it is still can't pass data.

Comment: If you surely get non-nil `photoVC`, see my edits. @chile

Comment: Is that  `- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil` init method in  PhotoViewController.m can not   write anything ?

Comment: You can put this designated initializer in your `PhotoViewController` with your custom parameters. Then, when you create it. You will need to use this initializer.

Comment: OK, it work, I did override the viewDidLoad,  but i write some set like  `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];` in `- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil` I write them in viewDidLoad method , and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Storyboard equal between two controller and controller runing.

```
PhotoViewController *photoVC = [[PhotoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
photoVC.images = images;
photoVC.index  = index;
photoVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
[self presentViewController:photoVC animated:YES completion:^{
    // code
}];
```